# How to get notified of a observer's unsubscribe action in a custom Observable in RxJava

Tags: observable, rx-java

I'm trying to wrap some listener-pattern based API to an Observable. My code roughly looks like following.

```
def myObservable = Observable.create({ aSubscriber ->
    val listener = {event -> 
      aSubscriber.onNext(event);                
    }
    existingEventSource.addListener(listener)
})
```

However, I want my observable to immediately remove the listener from the underlying existingEventSource when the observer calls subscription.unscribe(). How could I achieve this goal?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The `Subscriber` abstract class actually has a method `add` which lets you add `Subscription`s which will be unsubscribed with the subscriber.

```
def myObservable = Observable.create({ aSubscriber ->
    val listener = {event -> 
      aSubscriber.onNext(event);                
    }
    existingEventSource.addListener(listener)

    // Adds a lambda to be executed when the Subscriber un-subscribes from your Observable
    aSubscriber.add(Subscriptions.create(() -> existingEventSource.removeListener(listener)));
})
```

Think of `aSubscriber` as the `Observer` that subscribed to your `Observable`; we'll call it a `Subscriber`.  As long as the `Subscriber` is still subscribed to the `Observable`, the `Observable` can emit values.  But when that `Subscriber` un-subscribed then it should stop.  But if we want to get notified when the `Subscriber` unsubscribes we can register an `Action` to be run when it happens.  This is what the `add` method is used for.  As mentioned by @dwursteisen in the comments; you're basically registering a lambda that will be executed when the Subscriber un-subscribes.

It's also possible to have the Subscription be unsubscribe on a different Scheduler.  See [`MainThreadSubscription`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid/blob/1.1.0/rxandroid/src/main/java/rx/android/MainThreadSubscription.java) from the `rxanroid` project for an example of how to achieve that .

Here's an example of how you'd use it for unsubscribing on the main thread

```
aSubscriber.add(new MainThreadSubscription() {
    @Override
    protected void onUnsubscribe() {
        existingEventSource.removeListener(listener);
    }
});
```

Comment: Miguel, thanks for your answer, but I can't get it. Do you mind elaborating a little more, or pointing me to some related document or source code I can read?

Comment: Using the add method, your register a lambda that will be executed when your Observable is unsubscribe.

Comment: @xwk, I added a little explanation which will hopefully give you a better idea what's going on.

Comment: @MiguelLavigne. Thanks a lot. I understand now. But to be honest, this unsubscribing-hook mechanism is not as intuitive as other parts of RxJs to me. Not sure how it was designed this way.  BTW, you might have a typo. I guess you mean "The Subscriber abstract class actually HAS a method"

Comment: Is it possible to have the lambda run on a different scheduler?

Comment: @KirillRakhman I've edit the response with an example and where you can find similar code to achieve that.

Comment: Is the `unsubscribeOn` operator suited for that?

Comment: unsubscribeOn is different.  If you want to unsubscribe on the ui thread for instance then you'll need to implement the `Scheduler` interface accordingly or you can use the rxandroid's project AndroidSchedulers.mainThread() located [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid/blob/v1.0.0/rxandroid/src/main/java/rx/android/schedulers/AndroidSchedulers.java)

Comment: Does anyone know how to accomplish the same thing in RxJS 5 (for JavaScript)?